# Share Quick Parts with other users

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

How to share Outlook 2013 Quick Parts with other users on the network? So one user can create new for the others to use in their Outlook.

We use a Remote Desktop server, so we can also store it on this.

Answer (score 0):

Quick Parts are stored in NormalEmail.dotm

Look for it in your network equivalent of C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates.

You could store a copy of the one user's NormalEmail.dotm to be copied by the other users, to overwrite their own.

http://www.msoutlook.info/question/574

Comment: Yes, copy the NormalEmail.dotm to others maybe the only solution as what I can see Outlook don't use the Workgroup Template setting in Office. See Diane Poremsky's answer on http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-outlook/workgroup-templates-location-in-outlook-2007/20bcee68-6a6e-4b5f-bce0-8e0a841d14cb